# Two related questions on terminology on diagonals of polygons and angles between them

Tags: terminology, angle, polygons

In a convex polygon, I am inclined to construe the word "diagonal" to mean any of the segments connecting non-adjacent vertices and "edge" to mean any of the segments connecting adjacent vertices.

**Is there a standard term that means** any of the segments connecting two vertices regardless of whether they are adjacent?

If such a polygon is inscribed in a circle, consider the sequence of angles that includes $(1)$ the angle between a tangent ray and the adjacent edge, and $(2)$ the angle between that edge and the adjacent diagonal, and $(3)$ the angle between that diagonal and the next, $(4)$ and so on, until one reaches the angle between the next edge and the corresponding tangent ray. **Proposition:** That sequence of angles is the same at every vertex, modulo cyclic shifts. **Proof:** This is a corollary of your secondary-school geometry course.$\,\,\blacksquare\quad$ **Question:** Is there a name for that sequence of angles?

Comment: I'd use "chord" for a segment connecting two vertices.

Comment: @lulu : I wonder why I didn't think of that. I certainly use that for the segment connecting two points on a circle, and I define strict convexity of a function of one variable by saying the interiors of all of the chords of the graph are above the graph.

Comment: I suppose somebody might allow "chord" for a segment connecting any two points on the boundary, not necessarily vertices.  No idea on the angles.